# Is python with multiprocessing is suitable for multicamera with object detection?

Tags: python, opencv, python-multiprocessing, object-detection, python-multithreading

I am making a program which must connect to 20 cameras in rtsp and do object detection.

Just for testing, I did a simple program in python to connect to camera in rtsp, do object detection with opencv dnn and do some test with detection result before inserting element in mysql database.

I wish to keep all my work to do the next step with 20 cameras but I encountered some problems :

- If I try to get all frames from all cameras at same time by using multithreading (1 thread per camera), I have some delay and some thread crash because of frame buffering. It doesn't acquire all frames and exceeds the buffer
- I tried the multiprocessing by creating one process per cameras. For each process, I instantiate one opencv dnn net but my GPU has not enought GPU memory ...
- I tried to create one process per cameras and get frame by using multiprocessing Pipe but it takes to much time to send and received one frame (0.05 - 0.08 seconds).

I do not know how to do my final program with 20 cameras.
Python multithreading doesn't work because of python GIL.
Python multiprocessing demands to many ressource or take too much time to communication one frame by using Pipe ou Queue.

May be, Python is not the right langage to do what I need and I have to switch to C++.

I want to have some advice.

Thanks

Comment: Moving from Python to C++... well, let's just say there's a _lot_ of space on the performance / ease-of-use continuum between those two points.

Comment: While this question is much too broad to be answerable, let me make a point that you can build a system that uses multiple processes in Python without actually using the `multiprocessing` module. Thus, exactly how to split the work (and which data to pass "over the wire" between processes -- and whether you want to use SHM, or sockets, or whatever else to pass that data) is something fully within your control as developer.

Comment: ...having mentioned SHM -- have you looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html ? Much more efficient to pass a large object like a video buffer as a SHM segment than to serialize it, run it through a pipe and deserialize it on the other side.

Comment: BTW, if I were looking for a language that was faster than Python but less horrible than C++, with OpenCV support, I'd probably end up poking at https://juliaopencv.github.io/

Comment: Moving from Python to C++ is not a problem for me. I already have years of development in this langage. A collegue already did some project in python and I want to learn this langage. Of course, Python is very easy to use but some point like GIL asks me to find workarounds to do more complex programs.

Comment: I need to benchmark Multiprocessing shared memory but it could be interesting in my case. Thanks

Comment: I've been at more than one job where we prototyped in Python and rewrote to something else (Clojure in one case, Go in another) when performance became a showstopper. But yes, if you're already comfortable with C++, that's the obvious place to go.

Comment: Hum ok ! Thanks for your answers :) 
I will bench socket and SHM solution. Before switching to C++, I want to know the limitation of Python or a solution. That why I am asking the question.

Comment: Worth noting is that possibly asyncronous processing using `asyncio` might be a way to stick to python. Depends on where the bottleneck is but probably this might be an alternative.